# Override generic methods through interfaces

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have some contents, generated by this interface:

```
public interface Content {
    void addListener(ContentListener<?> listener);
}
```

Like `GenericContent`:

```
public interface GenericContent extends Content {
    @Override
    void addListener(GenericContentListener listener);
}
```

These are `ContentListener` and `GenericContentListener`

```
public interface ContentListener<T extends Content> {
    void ping(T content);
}

public interface GenericContentListener extends ContentListener<GenericContent> 
{
}
```

My problem is that the method `addListener` into `GenericContent` is a double error:

- The method `addListener(ContentListener<GenericContent>)` of type `GenericContent` must override or implement a supertype method
- Name clash: The method `addListener(ContentListener<GenericContent>)` of type `GenericContent` has the same erasure as `addListener(ContentListener<?>)` of type `Content` but does not override it

How can I obtain the same effect using a different technique?

Comment: Content class is not generic - what is T in the method? It should be typed

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `@Override` annotation.  Typically, you use `@Override` in a class and not an interface, using it to tell you that this method must override another, and if it ever fails to (like if the super class method signature changes), a compilation error is thrown.  Doing that made things compile for me.  I also made one tweak to the structure:

```
public interface Content {
  void addListener(ContentListener<? extends Content> listener);
}  

public interface GenericContent extends Content {
  void addListener(GenericContentListener listener);
}

public interface ContentListener<T extends Content> {
  void ping(T content);
}

public interface GenericContentListener extends ContentListener<GenericContent> 
{
}
```

Now in addition to that, you might want to consider redefining `Content` and then `GenericContent` like this:

```
public interface Content<T extends Content> {
  void addListener(ContentListener<T> listener);
}  

public interface GenericContent extends Content<GenericContent> {
  void addListener(GenericContentListener listener);
}
```

As it stands, your `Content` interface will allow a `ContentListener` of any type of `Content` to be added.  This change enforces that the `ContentListener` added must be for the type of `Content` that this is.

Then, you could probably take it a step further and do this:

```
public interface Content<T extends Content, L extends ContentListener<T>> {
  void addListener(L listener);
}  

public interface GenericContent extends Content<GenericContent, GenericContentListener> {

}
```

Now when someone implements `GenericContent`, it is assumed that the `addListener` method signature will be:

```
void addListener(GenericContentListener listener);
```

Comment: Using of generics in Content was an idea I had but, because the customer will use the Content interface ONLY, it's annoying to have the warning because the "<?,?>" is not inserted. But I think this is the only way... :\ Thank you!